# How to detect screen taps outisde ModalNavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack Compose's `ModalNavigationDrawer` composable. I'm facing a problem in which the `ModalNavigationDrawer` gesture cannot work in conjunction with `HorizontalPager`'s gesture, so I've disabled the gesture in `ModalNavigationDrawer` altogether. I have a button to open the drawer, but now, with the gesture disabled, I cannot close it by simply tapping outside the drawer. I've tried implementing it myself, but with no luck: as soon as the drawer is opened, no click can be read from the other composables, and the only clicks that can be read are the one inside the drawer, but I want to be able to read clicks that are also outiside it. I've tried wrapping the entire `ModalNavigationDrawer` and its content inside a `Box` with the `clickable` Modifier, but it doesn't work when the `ModalNavigationDrawer` is open. It seems to me that there is absolutely no way to read a click outside the drawer. It this true?